# Printer options follow Office documents

Tags: printing

One person (John) creates an Office document, and prints this document to his HP printer which is using HP Universal Printing PS (v4.7) driver. He has got Job Storage (Personal job) enabled for this printer, with custom username and a personal PIN.

He later sends this document in an e-mail to his colleagues.

Another person (Anne) opens the document, and tries to print the document to her HP printer (also using HP Universal Printing driver), but is not able to fetch it on the printer.

The Job Storage options from Johns computer follows the Office Excel document, so Anne has to change this manually to her username and her PIN before she can print.

What on earth is causing this, and how do we fix it?

Comment: Tested a bit more, and this seems to only affect Excel document, not Word documents.